# webapp : email program on linux for yahoo small biz email

Tags: mail-server

I have a linux home server where I am developing some webapps, mainly written in java. I would like these apps to be able to send email thru my isp using my yahoo email accounts. (I have a paid small business email acct).

Is it best to use something like ssmpt, or is postfix or sendmail a better option? Is sendmail used when your server is the ssmtp server, or can I use it when I pass an email along to my yahoo acct for sending?

thanks.
bp

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a java developer, but after a short search I found this tutorial, which seems to be helpful at [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

If you want to send an email via your yahoo account using smtp seems the best way in my opinion, because it's the direct way and obviously there are already a ready-to-use lib.